# How to validate a wysihtml5-editor textarea field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am inserting a form in database and description is important so i want to make textarea field required.
Controller

```
function get()
    {
            $data =array('success' => false,'message' =>array());
            $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('msg', 'Description', 'trim|required|max_length[1000]');
            $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('feed_title', 'Feed Title', 'required');
            $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('feed_link', 'Feed Link', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">','</p>');
            if($this->form_validation->run()== false)
            {
                foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
                {
                    $data['message'][$key] = form_error($key);
                }
            }
            else
            { 
                $data['success']=true;
            }
            echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

Form page

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="add_feed" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div id="feed_success"></div>
      <form method="post" id="feed_form" action="<?php echo base_url()?>welcome/get">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group clearfix">
            <label>Feed Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="feed_title" id="feed_title" placeholder="Enter Feed Title"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group clearfix">
            <label>Feed Link</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="feed_link" id="feed_link" placeholder="Enter Feed Link"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group clearfix">
            <label>Feed Short Description</label>
            <textarea class="textarea form-control" placeholder="Message" name="msg" style="width: 100%; height: 125px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Feed</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Ajax function

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".textarea").wysihtml5({}); 
       $('#feed_form').on('submit',function(form){
                   form.preventDefault(); 
                   var me = $(this);

                   $.ajax({
                    url:me.attr('action'),
                    type:'post',
                    data:me.serialize(),
                    dataType:'json',
                    success:function(response){
                        if(response.success == true){
                            $("#feed_form")[0].reset();
                           $('#feed_success').addClass('alert alert-success').html("Feed Add Successfully!");
                           $('div.form-group').removeClass('alert alert-danger').find('.text-danger').remove();
                           $('div.form-group').removeClass('alert alert-success').find('.text-success').remove();
                        }
                        else{
                            $.each(response.message,function(key,value){
                                var element = $("#"+key);
                                element.closest('div.form-group').removeClass('alert alert-danger')
                                .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'alert alert-danger' : 'alert alert-success').find('.text-danger').remove();
                                element.after(value);
                            });


                        }
                    }
                   });
                });
    });
</script>
```

Required is not working for it for other two inputs its working.

Comment: Check the value passing by your textarea. sometime it will pass a empty `<p>` tag. So in your codeigniter validation will true with require condition.

Comment: ok i check if textarea field have default value

Comment: is it working... if not come to chat ill explain more https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146504/codeigniter

Comment: its not working